# How to unzip audio.aecdump?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I have a dump from chrome://webrtc-internals and I want to unzip it. How I can do this? I know that I can use unpack_aecdump but where can I found this?

Answer (score 2):

## Getting `unpack_aecdump`

You need `unpack_aecdump`, which you can obtain as follows:

1. Set up a WebRTC development environment following the instructions at https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/.
2. Once you have a repository (so after completion of `gclient sync`), create the build directory:

   ```
   gn gen out/Release --args='is_component_build=false'
   ```
3. And finally, build the executable <sup>(see [unpack.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git/+/0e3213a18ceceb325f5b679f6eea7aff12059960/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/test/unpack.cc) for source code and [build.GN](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git/+/0e3213a18ceceb325f5b679f6eea7aff12059960/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/BUILD.gn#606) for build flags and dependencies)</sup>:

   ```
   ninja -C out/Release/ unpack_aecdump
   ```

The `is_component_build=false` flag ensures that the "unpack_aecdump" binary can be used in isolation. If you omit the flag, then components builds are turned on by default (as you can see from `gn args out/Release --list` after running `gn gen out/Release` without args). In this case, libraries are separated from the main binary and you need to copy multiple files if you want to share the binary with others (not just "unpack_aecdump" but also "libprotobuf_lite.so").

The total size of my repository after following the above steps is 7 Gb. About 1Gb for the repository, 5.5Gb for external dependencies and 0.5Gb for the built artifacts. The first two steps can take a while, especially on poor networks. The actual build step finishes within a minute for me. The binary itself is just 3MB.

<sup>(tested with https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git/+/0e3213a18ceceb325f5b679f6eea7aff12059960)</sup>

## Using `unpack_aecdump`

After building `unpack_aecdump` I copied it to a different location and used it as follows:

```
./unpack_aecdump audio_debug.4440.aec_dump.1
```

The first line below is the input file, the others are the output files (file size in bytes at the front). **If the output files already exist they are overwritten**.

```
163865593 audio_debug.4440.aec_dump.1
      643 settings.txt
 39862916 reverse0.wav
 21696044 ref_out0.wav
 19933244 input0.wav
```

Do note that `input0.wav` is exactly the same file as `audio_debug.4440.source_input.1.wav`, which I also got from `chrome://webrtc-internals` together with the `aecdump` file.

The meaning of those files are also explained in https://groups.google.com/d/msg/discuss-webrtc/NxPHdEAyU9k/QcH-DkVtD6oJ:

> - reverse.pcm: the received audio from the network, bound for rendering.
> - input.pcm: the captured audio, before audio processing.
> - ref_out.pcm: the captured audio, after audio processing, bound for the network.

The output format (including file names) can be customized, see [the source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git/+/0e3213a18ceceb325f5b679f6eea7aff12059960/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/test/unpack.cc) or `--help` :

```
$ ./unpack_aecdump --help
 ( ... )
  Flags from ../../webrtc/modules/audio_processing/test/unpack.cc:
    -delay_file (The name of the delay file.) type: string
      default: "delay.int32"
    -drift_file (The name of the drift file.) type: string
      default: "drift.int32"
    -full (Unpack the full set of files (normally not needed).) type: bool
      default: false
    -input_file (The name of the input stream file.) type: string
      default: "input"
    -keypress_file (The name of the keypress file.) type: string
      default: "keypress.bool"
    -level_file (The name of the level file.) type: string
      default: "level.int32"
    -output_file (The name of the reference output stream file.) type: string
      default: "ref_out"
    -raw (Write raw data instead of a WAV file.) type: bool default: false
    -reverse_file (The name of the reverse input stream file.) type: string
      default: "reverse"
    -settings_file (The name of the settings file.) type: string
      default: "settings.txt"
    -text (Write non-audio files as text files instead of binary files.)
      type: bool default: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **unpack_aecdump** (it should be on out/Debug or out/Release if you compile all the targets.) to unpack the AEC debug dumps.

**Unpacking results:**

*reverse.pcm:* the received audio from the network, bound for rendering.

*input.pcm:* the captured audio, before audio processing.

*ref_out.pcm:* the captured audio, after audio processing, bound for the network.

Typically The pcm files are 16-bit linear, and usually mono with a 16 kHz sampling rate, but check settings.txt which might be created when using the unpack utility. The files can then be opened in any audio editor for analysis.

For more info: [Check discuss-webrtc post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/NxPHdEAyU9k/L4PRRp0PIw4J)

Comment: Can you explain me this line - "Use the unpack_aecdump (it should be on out/Debug or out/Release if you compile all the targets.) to unpack the AEC debug dumps." Where I should search unpack_aecdump?